# ¿Para qué sirve first()?

Tags: python-3.x, django, djangorestframework

Estoy en un curso de DJANGO-REST-FRAMEWORK pero tengo la duda de cual es su función.

Ejemplo:

```
return self.get_serializer().Meta.model.objects.filter(id = pk, state = True ).first()
```

Comment: La propia documentación de la herramienta que usas es un buen punto de partida: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#first

Comment: La respuesta a esta preguntas es: **LEM** -> ¡Lee el manual!

Comment: StackOverflow es un sitio para ayudarte a resolver tus preguntas, dudas, errores o problemas después de que hayas hecho una investigación previa, hayas intentado resolver tu duda por tu propia cuenta y aún tengas esa interrogante. Por favor no preguntes sin haber realizado [un mínimo esfuerzo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4884/cuanto-esfuerzo-se-espera-de-los-usuarios-de-stack-overflow). Te dejo este [artículo en inglés](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) que complementa el enlace anterior

Answer (score 1):

Según la doc es lo mismo que hacer esto:

```
try:
    p = Article.objects.order_by('title', 'pub_date')[0]
except IndexError:
    p = None
```

Vamos, devuelve el primer elemento encontrado de la búsqueda o None si no hay.

Te dejo el link a la doc donde te lo explica mejor! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first

Comment: Muchas gracias, como lo encontraste tan rápido?, yo me perdí en la documentación.

Comment: Buscando en la doc con el control F lul, cuanto mas se practica mas fácil se vuelve encontrar y solucionar los problemas, mucho animo con el curso!